# API-Manager: Separate JWT signing from HTTPS endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to setup WSO2 API Manager to pass signed JWT tokens to the backend services.

However I want to be able to use a different certificate to sign the JWT to the one that is used to secure the API Gateway URL and Carbon back-office.

What I'm struggling with is the correct combination of configuration values in `carbon.xml`, `catalina-server.xml` and `axis2.xml` to get the various bits working...
Unfortunately I've not found anything on the WSO2 docs site to assist either.

Any pointers?

Cheers
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

As per [the code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/AbstractJWTGenerator.java#L255), the Private key of [the keystore in each tenant](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Managing+Keystores+with+the+UI) is used for JWT signing.